# Peppertones "Salary" - Harmonic syncopation in swing rhythm

Tags: identify-this-genre, similar-artists, genre-characteristics

https://youtu.be/p8U4b9yVyx4

This song's rhythm section consists of 3 instruments: drum, bass, and an acoustic guitar.

When anticipation/syncopation happens with harmonic rhythm (Chord changes one triplet beat earlier than downbeat), usually drum, bass, guitar are syncopated together.
But sometimes drum and bass would play the downbeat and only guitar would be syncopated.

What are the differences?

Is it common practice to do alternate these two methods?

What is the style/genre called?

Where can I find more song arranged with swing rhythm style and anticipations(harmonic syncopations) like this?

Answer (score 2):

This is 70's jazz-funk pop.  Syncopated harmonies in general are characteristic of jazz, and the harmonic anticipations for emphasis are often used in funk. I'm not positive any of these following examples have this exact technique, but they are all good examples of the genre:

Here's Earth, Wind & Fire's cover of the Beatles' "[Got to Get You Into My Life](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKskYvTGEHE)"

Here's George Benson singing "[On Broadway](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ok__l1Acuwg)"

Here's [Lou Rawls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTVZ5pV8TYA)

Comment: I appreciate your comments. But I was expecting songs with similar arrangement of rhythm (drum/bass) Can you give me examples with more similar rhythm/arrangement style? For instance, this song used syncopated freddie green style comping for intro and walking bass throughout the song. None of your songs matches that pattern

Comment: @user10331890 I don't know if there's a genre description at that level of specificity, especially since this is kind of a fusion sound already.  But I'll see if I can find something a little closer in terms of the examples.